# Is there a more compact/elegant way to write this?

Tags: typescript

Kind of still new to JS/TS and the conventions that come along with them. I wrote this piece of code today and thought it just kind of looked *wrong*.

tldr: Look up depth-3 child using hierarchical-ordered names, while performing null-checks.

```
public loadChildChild(parentName: string, childName: string, childchildName: string) {
    var parent = myCollection.items.find(i => i.name === parentName)
    if(parent === undefined){
      console.error(`${parentName} not found in collection`);
    }
    else{
      var child = parent.children.find(c => c.name === childName)
      if(child === undefined){
        console.error(`${childName} not found in ${parentName}`);
      }
      else{
        var childChild = child.children.find(c => c.name === childChildName))
        if(childChild == undefined){
          console.error(`${childChildName} not found in ${parentName}>${childName}`)
        }
        else {
          this.selectedItem = childChild;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

To me this seems like its a pain to read, and that there's probably some standard convention - or JS/TS magic for cleaning this up.

Comment: Is it intentional that you still assigning `childChild` to `this.selectedItem` even if `childChild` is `undefined`? Because there's no `else` block there

Comment: @Owl Not intentional - just fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it cleaner by doing a falsy check (`(!parent)`) instead of strict `undefined` check,
and doing `return` on `console.error` so you don't need the `else` block

```
public loadChildChild(parentName: string, childName: string, childChildName: string) {
    var parent = myCollection.items.find(i => i.name === parentName)
    // Do a falsy check instead of strict undefined check, then return on console.error to eleminate else block
    if(!parent) return console.error(`${parentName} not found in collection`);

    var child = parent.children.find(c => c.name === childName)
    // Do a falsy check instead of strict undefined check, then return on console.error to eleminate else block
    if(!child) return console.error(`${childName} not found in ${parentName}`);
    
    var childChild = child.children.find(c => c.name === childChildName);
    if(!childChild) return console.error(`${childChildName} not found in ${parentName}>${childName}`);

    this.selectedItem = childChild;
}
```

Or if you don't care about `console.error` if `parent` is `undefined` or `child` is `undefined`, you can do [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) instead

```
public loadChildChild(parentName: string, childName: string, childChildName: string) {
    const childChild = myCollection
        .items.find(i => i.name === parentName)
        ?.children.find(c => c.name === childName)
        ?.children.find(c => c.name === childChildName);
    
    if(!childChild) return console.error(`${childChildName} not found in ${parentName}>${childName}`);

    this.selectedItem = childChild;
}
```

Comment: Got to learn even more than I was hoping for on this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I read the problem in a different way. Are there any guarantees that there isn't any parent with repetaed names or siblings with repeated names? Using find will lead it to try only the first record and would eventualy fail in his mission if the first parent was not the correct one to use, but another one with his same name.

Instead, I would test every item with filter.

One-liner loadChildChild:

```
myCollection.items.filter(i => i.name === parentName).map(j => j.children.filter(k => k === childName.name)).flat().map(l => l.children.filter(m => m === childChildName.name)).flat()
```

It returns an array with all corresponding childchild's or an empty array otherwise (but does not alarm which level the descendancy was broken).